# DATEADD() function doesn't return the adding value

Tags: mysql, sql, dateadd

I wanted to create a funcition that can add 30 days to the input date, but I got an error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '30, `last_date`);
END'

Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION expected_date ( 
  last__date DATE
)
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
   RETURN DATE_ADD(DAY, 30, `last_date`);
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Your input parameter is `last__date` with 2 underscores. Your return should be `return date_add(day, 30, last__date);`. Your function may be better suited to have 2 parameters - one called last__date and the other days_to_add. That way, you can use it to get expected date with 30 days, 60 days or however may days you pass to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION expected_date ( 
  pdate DATE
)
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
   RETURN DATE_ADD(pdate, interval 30 day);
END;
```